# Methane or LOX tank at Boca Chica

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, thermal, lox, methane

As we can see on this picture from Mary "@bocachicagal" on NASASpaceFlight, there are two types of tank near the test stand.

Some are black and others are white or bright and shiny metal, but why?

[image: SN5 on test stand]

Comment: The silvery tank is a test Starship tank undergoing cryogenic or pressure testing. The white tanks probably hold cryogenic LOX, LN or LNG. The black tanks may be for the water deluge system and/or parts of the system that hold a buffer of excess boil off methane before compression cooling and liquefaction.

Answer (score 0):

Normally cryo tanks are painted white to reduce the heat absorption.

Maybe they paint them black because they want to increase the pressure inside them.

Comment: If they need an increased but constant pressure they would not rely on sunshine.

Comment: What is the difference between a bright reflective metallic surface and white paint? Aren't both highly reflective and absorb a minimal amount of visible light from the Sun? Perhaps they differ in their absorbance of 300 K blackbody radiation from the environment? I don't actually know the answer to this. :-)

Comment: Polished metal in sunlight can get hot enough to raise blisters on your skin from touching it.  Sunlight in Texas is bright enough to do it.

Comment: @uhoh It's much easier to get a very reflective white paint than very reflective mirror polish. A common mirror has reflectance of ~80% while a good common white paint will exceed 90%. Steel tanks won't be better than mirrors.

Comment: If you get into 'ultra', like 99.99% like in high energy laser optics, dedicated mirrors will outperform paint, but % of reflection per dollar, white paint wins hands down.

Comment: @JRE I've never gotten metal blisters in Texas but I have noticed and been perplexed by shiny metal getting uncomfortably hot in the Sun. I suppose it's related not only to less-than-mirror-like metal surfaces absorbing 10-30% of incident power, but also metal's high thermal conductivity's ability to promptly flow so much of the collected heat back into a relatively cool finger in contact with it.

Comment: The metal cylinder in a Starship tank. It's the colour it's part of the hardware they are testing.